# Google Admin SDK Directory Members Patch Error 500

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm using the oauth playground for the Directory Members Update tool https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/patch

Whenever I try to update an existing member in the group I'm encountering an error 500 message. Is this a temporary issue or am I missing something.

When generating the request I am providing the groupKey, memberKey, and role:MEMBER for the patch body. If I provide the exact same arguments for the Update function things work just fine.

Thank you.

James

Comment: Were you able to figure a way around this? I ran in to this exact issue today. I was trying to work with the C# api but kept getting the 500 error. I tried working in the Playground and got the same issue, I can't seem to find any permutation to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Only the role should be in the body since its the only value that is changing.

Comment: I'm only putting in a single role. when I encounter the error

Comment: I meant don't include groupKey and member key in the body. It may be a bug with API explorer that it does, try using OAuth 2.0 playground.

Comment: This was with the playground. GroupKey and memberKey are parameters. The body only contained the role attribute.